# How to redirect from html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just for the sake of information,I want to know is there any way to redirect from html page to another , besides  `window.location.href` and  `window.location` ???

Comment: Depending on what you need, you could look into utilising htaccess on the server

Comment: i want to send a request to asp.net server! both methods are not suitable!

Comment: Sending a request is something entirely different than a redirect. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am sending form data to server and then server redirects to some page. actually it is sending twice requests to server . that's why exploring some new method! @Merguez

Answer (score 2):

There is.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Remember to place it inside `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are neglecting the above mentioned, anyways here you go.

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP, but for frontend purposes:

You maybe want to look into `window.location.replace` since it bypasses the back-button which is often very annoying when it comes to redirects.

Comment: if i want to send a request to C# server, then ? @merguez

Comment: What do you mean: "send a request to C# server"? If you mean, that you're using C# a quick google gave me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can put this on your head balise

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time; URL=your_new_url">
```

Exemple

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=test.html">
```

to redirect after 5 seconds at test.html